# How to check if condition in foreach using logic app in efficient way?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have two array variables in for each i compare values one by one abd process further but issue is it is taking to much time for executing when I have 1000 of records.

Variable_1 having around 10 records 
Variable_2 which is output if HTTP will have around 1000+ records

```
Variable_1 = 
[
    {

      "Name": "AAA",
      "OwnerId": "121a",

    },
    {

      "Name": "BBB",
      "OwnerId": "123b",

    },
    ...
]
```

and

```
Variable_2 = 
[
    {     
      "Demo_Name": "AAA"     
    },
    {  
      "Demo_Name": "BBB"
    },
    {  
      "Demo_Name": "BBB"
    },
    {  
      "Demo_Name": "BBB"
    },
    {  
      "Demo_Name": "BBB"
    }
    .... 
]
```

I have used `2 for each one is for`Variable_1`and another is for`Variable_2``.

and comparing `Variable_1.Name == Variable_2.Demo_Name one by one`.

so when `Variable_2` is having more than `1000+ records` it took around a hour to check condition one by one

any solution for this to do it in a fast way?
outer loop is taking around 2h 
[image]

> If I try `concurrent execution` then `increment variable` set wrong
>   values

Comment: What did you set the Foreach concurrency?

Comment: Please paste the code

Comment: And preferably the 2 data arrays to test with.

Comment: can not set Foreach concurrency because using `increment variable` it affect the value of `increment variable`  what about Join parallel branches? how to use it here?

Comment: See my post, I offload the result to an Azure Storage Table, this is with full parallelism, 50 loops and if Var1 and Var2 switches place the filter is done within 10 seconds~

Answer (score 2):

I tried doing this with Azure Storage Tables as a source for the result, just to see how fast I could iterate through `Var2` with 1465 records and `Var1` with 9 records. I do it twice here to see just to figure out which way was easiest to do it in. The result here was XXXX matches, the values stored in an Azure Storage Table which I would fetch after the loops were done. I have added a Terminate Action which you could move them before the action `For each` just to see use one of them for each loop instead of both.

For the record, not sure if this is exactly what you want. Also with this way, if you switch the For each array to loop over `Var1` instead of `Var2` It was done in less then 10 seconds with all objects. If you make it into different arrays you can filter the two arrays, you can probably use an intersection also. All you need to do is to fetch the records from the Azure Storage Table which is in JSON notation, now with GUIDs as ids.

4 Minutes
[image: 4 Minutes]

This is the flow for the first one of the two loops, the one I like the most, feels cleaner.
[image]

Storage Table result which you would need to truncate or something when you are done or something:
[image: Azure Storage Table]

You need an Azure Storage Table to offload the results to.
When posting this I reduced `Var2` in size as it made no sense in posting 1600 objects.
Code:

`{
    "$connections": {
        "value": {
            "azuretables": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/*YOUR SUBSCRIPTION ID*/resourceGroups/*RESOURCEGROUP NAME*/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azuretables",
                "connectionName": "azuretables",
                "id": "/subscriptions/*YOUR SUBSCRIPTION ID*/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westeurope/managedApis/azuretables"
            }
        }
    },
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "For_each_2": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Condition": {
                                "actions": {
                                    "Insert_Entity": {
                                        "inputs": {
                                            "body": {
                                                "PartitionKey": "@{items('For_each_2')['Name']}",
                                                "RowKey": "@{guid()}"
                                            },
                                            "host": {
                                                "connection": {
                                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azuretables']['connectionId']"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "method": "post",
                                            "path": "/Tables/@{encodeURIComponent('stackoverflowforeachtmp')}/entities"
                                        },
                                        "runAfter": {},
                                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                                    }
                                },
                                "expression": {
                                    "and": [
                                        {
                                            "equals": [
                                                "@items('For_each_2')['Name']",
                                                "@items('For_each')['Demo_Name']"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "If"
                            }
                        },
                        "foreach": "@variables('TestValueVariable1')",
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Set_TestVariable2": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "runtimeConfiguration": {
                            "concurrency": {
                                "repetitions": 50
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "Foreach"
                    },
                    "Set_TestVariable1": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "TestValueVariable2",
                            "value": "@{items('For_each')['Demo_Name']}"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    },
                    "Set_TestVariable2": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "TestValueVariable1",
                            "value": "@variables('Variable 1')"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Set_TestVariable1": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@array(variables('Variable 2'))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each_3": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "concurrency": {
                        "repetitions": 50
                    }
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "For_each_3": {
                "actions": {
                    "Filter_array": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "from": "@array(variables('Variable 1'))",
                            "where": "@equals(items('For_each_3')['Demo_Name'], item()['Name'])"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Query"
                    },
                    "For_each_4": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Insert_Entity_2": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "body": {
                                        "EvaluationKey": "@{items('For_each_3')['Demo_Name']}-@{items('For_each_4')['Name']}",
                                        "Owner": "@{items('For_each_4')['OwnerId']}",
                                        "PartitionKey": "@{items('For_each_4')['Name']}",
                                        "RowKey": "@{guid()}"
                                    },
                                    "host": {
                                        "connection": {
                                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azuretables']['connectionId']"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "method": "post",
                                    "path": "/Tables/@{encodeURIComponent('stackoverflowforeachtmp')}/entities"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "ApiConnection"
                            }
                        },
                        "foreach": "@body('Filter_array')",
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Filter_array": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Foreach"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@array(variables('Variable 2'))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "TestValueVariable2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Get_entities": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azuretables']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/Tables/@{encodeURIComponent('stackoverflowforeachtmp')}/entities"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "paginationPolicy": {
                        "minimumItemCount": 30000
                    }
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Variable 1",
                            "type": "Array",
                            "value": [
                                {
                                    "Name": "AAA",
                                    "OwnerId": "121a"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Name": "BBB",
                                    "OwnerId": "123b"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Name": "AAA",
                                    "OwnerId": "123b"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Name": "BBB",
                                    "OwnerId": "123b"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Name": "FFF",
                                    "OwnerId": "123b"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Name": "BBB",
                                    "OwnerId": "123b"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Name": "DDD",
                                    "OwnerId": "123b"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Name": "CCC",
                                    "OwnerId": "123b"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Name": "BBB",
                                    "OwnerId": "123b"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Variable 2",
                            "type": "Array",
                            "value": [
                                {
                                    "Demo_Name": "AAA"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Demo_Name": "BBB"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Demo_Name": "CCC"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Demo_Name": "BBB"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Demo_Name": "BBB"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Demo_Name": "BBB"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Demo_Name": "BBB"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Demo_Name": "FFF"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Demo_Name": "BBB"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Demo_Name": "BBB"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Demo_Name": "FFF"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Demo_Name": "AAA"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Set_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "name": "TestValueVariable2",
                    "value": "@{length(body('Get_entities')?['value'])}"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Terminate": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "SetVariable"
            },
            "Terminate": {
                "inputs": {
                    "runStatus": "Succeeded"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_entities": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Terminate"
            },
            "TestValueVariable1": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "TestValueVariable1",
                            "type": "Array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "TestValueVariable2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "TestValueVariable2",
                            "type": "String"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "TestValueVariable1": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @adstra could you please help with my question? thanks